# What's a good way to find someone locally to help me with my investments?

Tags: stocks, investing, financial-advisor

I inherited a stock portfolio from my grandparents, and it has been sitting at the investment house where it was when I got it.

I want to move this portfolio somewhere where the fees are lower and where I will get good investment advice that trues up with my personal goals.  The internet has not been a good source of information because of SEO spammers.

What's a good process to follow to find a firm locally to be my investment house?  How hard is it to transfer assets from one house to another?

Answer (score 4):

Dave Ramsey has a list of [ELPs](http://www.daveramsey.com/elp/home/) (Endorsed Local Providers) of which I've only heard good things.  You can request an investment ELP [here](https://www.daveramsey.com/elp/investing).

Answer (score 3):

I would start by talking to a Fee-Only Financial Planner to make sure the portfolio fits with your goals.  You can find a list here: http://www.napfa.org/

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suggest personal referral. Ask all of your friends/family/neighbors/co-workers/dog-sitter what they think of their brokers until you find someone who loves his broker.

As for transferring assets, I've found it to be quite easy. It's in the new broker's best interest to get those assets, so he should be more than willing to help.